# Need help with power outlet wiring

Tags: electrical

[image]i hope someone can give me hand here

So i have a light on/off switch which i want to change into a power outlet switch, the thing is i'm a bit confused with the wiring.

The Light switch has - 2x red wires, 1x green wire, 1x white wire, can i even change it into a power outlet?

https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipP1U9oBc9B8eg7zCoUmUX5ggBP30nSmf1l4HCnB (light switch)

https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipOEnIPk8zhzqGeVciQw-yspDCWkpdEnWQ0dic4T (Power outlet)

UK plug

Thank you in advance

Comment: I was not able to view the pictures. Can you check the links?

Comment: Hi there, ive uploaded the light switch photo, sorry about that

Comment: My other outlets have the normal x1 black, x1 red and x1 green cables

Comment: Are there any other switches that also control what this switch controls?

Comment: Nope, the switch was just for 1 single light, nothing else, it was a single on/off switch, i hope that was what you were asking

Comment: actually i just noticed there is another switch, i never noticed it because i never used it, my bad